# ValueError validation loop

Tags: python

I'm starting out with Python after taking a class that taught us pseudocode. How could I make a validation loop to continue the function if a user inputted a decimal rather than a whole number? At its current state, I've gotten it to recognize when a user enters a number outside of the acceptable range, but if the user enters a decimal number, it crashes. Is there another validation loop that can recognize a decimal?

```
def main():
    again = 'Y'
    while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        strength_score = int(input('Please enter a strength score between 1 and 30: '))

        # validation loop
        while strength_score < 1 or strength_score > 30 :
            print ()
            print ('Error, invalid selection!')
            strength_score = int(input('Please enter a whole (non-decmial) number between 1 and 30: '))

        # calculations
        capacity = (strength_score * 15)
        push = (capacity * 2)
        encumbered = (strength_score * 5)
        encumbered_heavily = (strength_score * 10)

        # show results
        print ()
        print ('Your carrying capacity is' , capacity, 'pounds.')
        print ('Your push/drag/lift limit is' , push, 'pounds.')
        print ('You are encumbered when holding' , encumbered, 'pounds.')
        print ('You are heavyily encumbered when holding' , encumbered_heavily, 'pounds.')
        print ()

        # technically, any response other than Y or y would result in an exit. 
        again = input('Would you like to try another number? Y or N: ')
        print ()
    else:
        exit()

main()
```

Comment: Please provide error message :) It will help a lot.

Comment: Have a look at error handling, specifically ``try .. except ...`` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want the behavior to be:

1. If you want to accept non-integer numbers, just use `float(input())`. If you want to accept them but turn them into integers, use `int(float(input()))` to truncate or `round(float(input()))` to round to the nearest integer.
2. If you want to print an error message and prompt for a new number, use a try-catch block:

   ```
   try:
       strength_score = int(input('Please enter a strength score between 1 and 30: '))
   except ValueError:
       again = input("Invalid input, try again? Y / N")
       continue # skip the rest of the loop
   ```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have `strength_score` as an int, and not a float.

Try changing

```
strength_score = int(input('Please enter a strength score between 1 and 30: '))
```

to

```
strength_score = float(input('Please enter a strength score between 1 and 30: '))
```

Tested with `0.1` and `0.0001` and both are working properly.